# Android Custom Container with Custom Children

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Custom LayoutContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623289/android-custom-layoutcontainer)

I am designing a Custom layout that extends a Linear Layout. The children for this Layout will also be Custom Linear Layouts. Can some one show me how i can do this ? I have defined all the layouts the parent container as well. My linear parent has all three constructors defined, cause i want to adding custom params via xml. How how do i inflate the child contents? Will these be automatically inflated ? Can someone show me some code to get me started? I am new to Android and really puzzled where to get started .

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The children will be automatically inflated. If you want to do some further initialization after the children have been inflated, you can override `onFinishInflate` in your container.

As far as using custom attributes, this is described in the training topic [Creating a View Class](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).